# `The connection to [ws] was interrupted while the page was loading.` with Vue CLI in Firefox using proxy

Tags: vue.js, webpack, firefox, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) and create a new Vue CLI project `vue create test-project`.
2. Using Vue 3 and Yarn.
3. Update the `vue.config.js` file to point to a custom dev server with a proxy:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://test.me',
  },
});
```

4. Run `yarn serve` inside the project directory.
5. Go to http://localhost:8080 in Firefox and check out the console.

The websocket for the Webpack dev server keeps failing with the message `The connection to ws://[ip]:8080/ws was interrupted while the page was loading.`

This doesn't happen when there is no proxy. I cannot figure out why it's happening or how to stop it.

Comment: Running into this as well. Even in a plain vanilla js/html page, this issue is present.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and telling it not to proxy websockets solved the issue:

```
{
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
         target: 'http://test.me',
         ws: false,
       }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: For me this fixed the issue (the Hot Module Replacement now does not get unresponsive anymore), although the console message remains.